# They say I should work on bigger things

Tags: knowledge, connect-wall

I'm an important figure in my field. Who am I?

```
-----------------------------------------------
|   seat    |    heat   |   fish    |   line  |
|---------------------------------------------|
|    go     |    beat   |   music   |  lunch  |
|---------------------------------------------|
|  grumpy   |    end    |   sand    |   nap   |
|---------------------------------------------|
|   lock    |   stock   |  stream   |   walk  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Groups:

> **CAT**: grumpy, fish, nap, walk
>  **LIVE**: music, go, stock, stream
>  **DEAD**: heat, line, end, lock
>  **BOX**: seat, lunch, sand, beat
>
>  (Originally I had deadbeat and lockbox which also fits, but the intended solution was deadlock and beat box).

Pointing to:

> Schrodinger's cat, the thought experiment in quantum physics about a cat in a box that could simultaneously be alive and dead.  Which means the answer is **Erwin Schrodinger**, the Nobel winning physicist who invented Schrodinger's cat.

Title refers to:

> Quantum mechanics, which is normally used in micro systems, being theoretically valid (though computationally impractical) for macroscopic systems.  (From Aaron Hayman in comments)

Comment: Nice. Minor point though, the final answer should be a name since the question is 'Who am I?'. That'll be enough :) But, optionally, if you want to explain the title, that'd be fun.

Comment: You inverted rot13(ORNGOBK naq QRNQYBPX).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier it works the way I have it too rot13(qrnqorng naq ybpxobk), but I guess the OP has to say.

Comment: @JS1 I initially made it like what Arnaud said. But your answer is also valid and right. What you're pointing at is also right. But the final answer should be the _name of the person_, mate. That way I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Luke sorry I didn't have enough time earlier to fix my answer.

Comment: Rejva Fpue**ö**qvatre, vg fubhyq or.

Comment: I'm not sure Schrödinger invented the cat. I think he discovered it. Assuming it was actually there.

Comment: Title refers to rot13(dhnaghz zrpunavpf, juvpu vf abeznyyl hfrq va zvpeb flfgrzf, orvat gurbergvpnyyl inyvq (gubhtu pbzchgngvbanyyl vzcenpgvpny) sbe znpebfpbcvp flfgrzf.)

Comment: @AaronHayman you got it!